# zbar_ros, cv_camera - dirty reads of barcodes

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody.
I'm trying to read barcodes using cv_camera and zbar_ros. Below you can read what I am doing.

```
$ rosrun cv_camera cv_camera_node /cv_camera/image_raw:=image
</pre>
<pre>[ INFO] [1496521778.337223498]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1496521778.337350789]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/wojtas/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml
[ INFO] [1496521778.337442923]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/wojtas/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml]
[ WARN] [1496521778.337476985]: Camera calibration file /home/wojtas/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml not found.
</pre>
<pre>
$ rosrun zbar_ros barcode_reader_node
```

```
[ INFO] [1496521948.392267314]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
```

After trying reading barcode from my bottle of beer :) I get

```
$ rostopic echo /barcode
</pre>
<pre>data: 4321136100317
---
data: 7611166100317
---
data: 7225226100317
---
data: 8639213100317
---
data: 8342113100317
</pre>
When I'm using zbarcam application and reading the same barcode I get
<pre>
$ zbarcam
```

```
EAN-13:5900699100317
EAN-13:5900699100317
EAN-13:5900699100317
```

So I'm very confused. Why barcodes from /barcode topic are different from original barcode? Any ideas?

Additional info:

```
$ roscore 
...
ros_comm version 1.12.7

SUMMARY
========
PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.7

$ rostopic list
/barcode
/camera_info
/image
/image/compressed
/image/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/image/compressed/parameter_updates
/image/compressedDepth
/image/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/image/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/image/theora
/image/theora/parameter_descriptions
/image/theora/parameter_updates
/rosout
/rosout_agg
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263130/zbar_ros,-cv_camera---dirty-reads-of-barcodes/) by [wojtas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30622/wojtas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-06-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-06-04**:
I don't anything about zbar, but my first debugging step would be to try to capture an image through ROS as a PNG and then run both the ROS and non-ROS versions of zbar on it; to figure out if the difference is on the image capture side or in the zbar_ros node.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-06-04**:
The [image_saver](http://wiki.ros.org/image_view#image_view.2BAC8-diamondback.image_saver) and [image_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/image_publisher) nodes will probably be helpful.

**Comment by [wojtas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30622/wojtas/) on 2017-06-05**:
Thank you ahendrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dirty reads aren't connected neither with **zbar_ros** nor with **cv_camera**.
I've played with **zbarcam** little longer and it showed me that dirty reads happens.

So I think the "problem" is connected with zbar library. This library is not as reliable as I thought :(.

---

Originally posted by [wojtas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30622/wojtas/) with karma: 36 on 2017-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1